# Distribution of loans by types of interest

Tags: reference-request, data-request, interest-rate

Im looking for some kind of report that would inculde data on the distribution of loans by types of interest(fixed/floating), spesificaly global not just for one country(developed, undeveloped, developing world). If any of you have known to stumble upon such reports would be grand

Loans between corporations, that is what im looking for.

Comment: Your answer seems to be only about the World Bank. In your question are you talking about intergovernmental loans or loans to people?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.oecd.org/economy/surveys/

To complete the answer, I recommend reading the full economic studies country by country: banks, finance, debt, economic sectors, taxation, economic risk etc. Read these studies before making décisions !

I sincerely believe that these studies will help you in your economic analysis and banking.

We must understand why an interest rate is high or low, why the volume of business loans is strong or weak.

Only this type of study can explain and analyze the data rates between companies, and compare from one country to another.

**For example, credit rates can reach 15% in an African country because the inflation rate is high and the rate of the central bank is very high! Without economic studies, it is impossible to compare.**

**French/Français** :

Pour compléter la réponse, je conseille de lire les études économiques complètes pays par pays : l'écosystème bancaire, les financements, la dette publique, les études par secteurs économiques, la fiscalité, les risques économiques etc. Lire ces études avant de prendre des décisions !

Je pense sincèrement que ces études vont vous aider dans votre analyse économique et bancaire.

Il faut comprendre pourquoi un taux d'intérêt est fort ou faible, comprendre pourquoi le volume des prêts professionnels est fort ou faible.

Ces études peuvent vous expliquer et aider à analyser les données concernant les taux entre les entreprises, et les comparer d'un pays à un autre avec une approche globale.

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question. Could you link to a specific survey? Diese Post scheint die originelle Frage nicht zu beantworten. Können Sie bitte nach eine bestimmte Umfrage linken?

Comment: @denesp . I understand your comment, but let me respond politely and entirely friendly explanation. Bank numbers are shown on the studies. I give tools to compare professional loans digits of a zone to another. What is the point of having numbers without having the intellectual and economic elements to compare and analyze ? Moreover, I pointed out from the start of my answer. It's a complement. And then I say the reason for the need to read these economic country studies to compare loans inside an economic area with another. My gracious respects. –

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. I am worried that the tools you give are not as accessible as you think. For example having read your answer I still do not know which of the myriad surveys the site I should look at. Perhaps others will have the same problem. It could also be that I am at fault.

Comment: I read (carefully) your suggestion. 
Read all publications country by country, topic by topic. It is difficult but necessary to have the information necessary to understand and analyze a professional production credit in a particular political and economic situation. You can then refine by looking at the top right of the page.

Answer (score 0):

thats the on i found http://siteresources.worldbank.org/EXTANNREP2013/Resources/9304887-1377201212378/9305896-1377544753431/IBRD_FinancialStatements.pdf, but if someone have seen somthing more global...